# What can I add to jump to the page the hash is on THEN animate scroling

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to how to get my jQuery code to allow me to jump to the new page before it animates the scrolling to the hash... Right now it only animates scrolling to the hash if I'm on the page that the hash is located. Is there a line of code I can insert here so it will pull the anchor page the hash is located on first and put it in the url?

The hash is being pulled from a wordpress menu custom link I just replaced with the hash so when you press the menu button the hash just shows up in the url box after the page your on and doesn't put the anchor behind it. In this case I want to go to the 'about' page before it sticks the hash after it.

Here's what I'm working with right now

### parallax scroller

```
    >(jQuery); 
    (function($){
        $.fn.jExpand2 = function(){
          var element = this;
    $(".detail-head").next("div").hide();
    $(element).find(".detail-head").click(function() {
       $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
   });
       }  
    
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
      }
     }
  });
   });  
 **`strong text`**})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code that performs the check/animation into a function, then check for `window.location.hash` on page load, and call the function, passing in the hash.

```
if(window.location.hash){
   doScrollToAndAnimate(window.location.hash);
}

function doScrollToAndAnimate(hash){
    //code inside of your click function currently
}
```